# C# Detects the maximum and lists all the elements that acquire

Tags: c#

Please can somebody help me with C# issue?

Create a program that detects the maximum and lists all the elements that acquire this value. The name of the pupil and the height of the pupil will be entered at the entrance with the precision per cm. At the output, the program lists the maximum altitude of all pupils and the next line of the names of all pupils who reach this maximum height (in the same order as the names were entered).

Inputs:

```
Martin Novacek 171
Bohumil Betak 177
Ladislav Zlatohlavek 150
Hana Drbohlavova 177
```

Result:

```
177
Bohumil Betak
Hana Drbohlavova
```

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ulozka5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input;
            int max = 0;
            string[] array = new string[9999];


            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)   // inputs
            {
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input == "" || input == null)
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref array, i);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    array[i] = input;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)  //max value
            {            
                var number = int.Parse(new string(array[i].Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
                if (max < number)
                {
                   max = number;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(max);

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)  //compare with max
            {
                var cislo = int.Parse(new string(array[i].Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
                if (cislo == max)
                {
                    var name =  Regex.Replace(array[i], @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but scholar system gave me Score 20 for this :( ... Thanks for any idea..

Comment: So if the code runs fine, what is your question?

Comment: 20 out of 100? and @KlausGütter I think the question is how can it be improved?

Comment: "scholar system gave me Score 20 for this"... what does this mean?

Comment: for 9999? Should not you use While not escape read new item? Instead of using array of string use List<Person> (Person: Name, Height) and Parse string input when reading.

Comment: If @Matt is correct, and this you are asking to improve your code, you should post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If something with your code isn't working, please make your question clearer and someone will be able to help.

Comment: Im a beginner in C# (I program in Delphi) , so I dont know if there are  "non effective lines" or what should be wront with it ? :/

Comment: @Matt .. Ok, thx :)

Comment: @LeszekRepie Maybe thats the way .. use List instead string array.. I´ll try.. Thanks Leszek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of ways in which you can improve the code. Here are some suggestions.

**Input Part**

Instead of defining a huge array upfront, you can create a List and wait for User to enter a special terminating character (in this case, Programs waits for User to enter "q" to end input). Also, you can use regex to parse the Name/Altitude parts and store in a object.

```
string input = string.Empty;    
var list = new List<Pupils>();
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<name>[a-zA-Z\s]+)\s+(?<altitude>[0-9]+)",RegexOptions.Compiled);
while((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "q")
{
    var matches = regex.Match(input.Trim());
     list.Add(new Pupils
    { 
        Name = matches.Groups["name"].Value, 
        Altitude = int.Parse(matches.Groups["altitude"].Value)
    });
}
```

Where Pupils is defined as

```
public class Pupils
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Altitude {get;set;}
}
```

**Querying Max and related Users**

Then you can calculate Max Altitude can be found using Linq

```
var maxAltitude = list.Max(x=>x.Altitude);
```

With maxAltitude in hand, you can now parse the Users with max value.

```
var result = list.Where(x=>x.Altitude.Equals(maxAltitude)).Select(x=>x.Name);
```

Complete code:

```
void Main()
{
    string input = string.Empty;    
    var list = new List<Pupils>();
    var regex = new Regex(@"(?<name>[a-zA-Z\s]+)\s+(?<altitude>[0-9]+)",RegexOptions.Compiled);
    while((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "q")
    {
        var matches = regex.Match(input.Trim());
         list.Add(new Pupils
        { 
            Name = matches.Groups["name"].Value, 
            Altitude = int.Parse(matches.Groups["altitude"].Value)
        });
    }
    
    var maxAltitude = list.Max(x=>x.Altitude);
    
    var result = list.Where(x=>x.Altitude.Equals(maxAltitude)).Select(x=>x.Name);
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Max Altitude :{maxAltitude}");
    foreach(var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    
}

public class Pupils
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Altitude {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but isn't code review in this forum generally not allowed?

Comment: @Greg Not sure about it, but my own guess says you are right. If so, I can delete my answer and direct Pan to the right forum

Comment: PERFECT ..Thanks very much .. Btw: Happy New Year Anu , this really help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun.
Your code can be little bid simpler if you will use separator character between name and height.

```
// Get pupils and calculate max height
var pupils = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
              .Select(i => Console.ReadLine())
              .TakeWhile(input => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) == false)
              .Select(input => input.Split(':'))
              .Select(values =>
              {
                  var name = values.First();
                  var validHeight = int.TryParse(values.Last(), out int height);
                  return (Name: name, Height: height, Valid: validHeight);
              })
              .Where(pupil => pupil.Valid)
              .ToList();

var maxHeight = pupils.Max(pupil => pupil.Height);

// Build output string
var output = 
    pupils.Where(pupil => pupil.Height == maxHeight)
          .Aggregate(new StringBuilder().AppendLine(maxHeight.ToString()),
                     (builder, pupil) => builder.AppendLine(pupil.Name));

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio , great idea :)